# simulate api calling like happened in flash

Tags: php, .net, remoting, amf

I am trying to figure out how can I call php functions running on remote of shoretel IP phone .

I can access it through browser by simple IP and it is flash player script but I want to do few things programmatically and I don't find any help to do the same.

The flash player app is calling following api
https:///gateway.php?PHPSESSID=6432fc5f0999d0f4536fced79b95

and in payload of this it is calling php function like LSRoom_Remoting.getHeaderInfo

I am trying but getting error like "Malformed AMF message"

Here is the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;
        var content = new StringContent("LSRoom_Remoting.getBoardID", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-amf");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept","*/*");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Length", "47");
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-amf");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=3cbc7ff268e80e78e1458a4adfdd1f56");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DNT", "1");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "10.6.32.21");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://10.6.32.21/interface/ls_interface.swf");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://10.6.32.21");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "ShockwaveFlash/32.0.0.114");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36");
            var result = client.PostAsync(string.Format("https://10.6.32.21/gateway.php?PHPSESSID={0}", "3cbc7ff268e80e78e1458a4adfdd1f56"), content).Result;
            //var result = client.DownloadString("https://10.6.32.21/interface/interface.php?uniqueKey=152322314997139&brand=shoretel&key=");
            var obj = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Content.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it seems likely, that the `PHPSESSID` is long expired, while not using one from a recent request; because the default timeout is 15 minutes. in case it had not yet been expired, you still have to build a proper `AMF` message, which consist of a header and a body. there is a library for that: [amfphp](http://www.amfphp.org/docs/), which at least should provide some clue how it should look alike, despite it is written in `PHP`.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for looking into it. I have tried different session ID, even requesting from browser and then captured that session id and tried to make sure its not expired. I will look into amfphp. I am wondering although the web application developed in flash or which required flash, can't the underlying model should be simple request response model? Because at the end what we need to call is a remote php function. Do we have to build the AMF message?

Comment: @user393014 there might be further session variables set besides the `PHPSESSID`, it's just a strange way to present these cookies to the issuing server. ideally the same client which perform the login should perform subsequent requests (as it is common with most kinds of API interaction, or cURL scripts). I'd guess, that it might complain about the AMF message being malformed, because it's a string and not byte-array: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format

Comment: there's even an `AMF` tag on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amf ...and it is unclear if this is an `AMF self-contained packet`, `AMF0` or `AMF3`. by any chance, switch from `HTTPS` or `HTTP`, then it should be easy to capture the packets, in order to reverse & reproduce the request.